# Why aren't the buttons on the same level?

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form name="profiel" action="profiel.php"><input class="button2" type="submit" value="Jens Boonen" /></form></td>
        <td width="94%"><form name="zoeken" action="zoeken.php"><input type="submit" class="button2" value="Zoeken"> </form></td>
        <td><form name="loguit" action="loguit.php"><input class="button2" type="submit" value="Log-Out" /></form></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Why aren't the buttons on a same level?

As requested the CSS :

```
.button2 {
    background-color:black;
    display:block;
    line-height:200%;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin:0.5%;
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

All 3 buttons are "button2" , and the "zoeken" and "log out" are on the same level ( the log out isn't show in the picture ) , but the name bar ( in this case Jens Boonen ) isn't

Comment: Because we don't know how your CSS looks like. Please provide your CSS.

Comment: Added it specially for you hahaha

Comment: I look upon your html and immediately think of 2 questions:
1) Why are you using tables for layout?
2) Why are you using forms? For the logout action, it's an okay thing to do, but couldn't the other "forms" just use an anchor tag instead?

Comment: What browser are you viewing it in?

Comment: Can you give a link to your site, please (zou fijn zijn!). Otherwise, we can't help. Or as I said, give your full, relevant, CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `margin: 0.5%` and there seems to be a missing `/` at the end of the second input.

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/684bT/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your HTML ist wrong?

You have 4 `<td>` but only 3 `</td>`.

Comment: The first <td> is wrong , that is just a mistake made , and removed already now , but that's not the problem , and the <tr> is opened if you look good

Comment: Which Browser do you used?

Answer (score 1):

Looking perfect for me. Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/684bT/

And it might be better to use `.button2 { color: #FFF; }` instead of `white`.

I guess you have to put all relevant `CSS` in here to reproduce your problem and fix it. If you don't know how, than give me a link to your website.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem to be the only problem, you also have only 2 buttons and the third is not showing.

First did you notice the extra  you have just after ?
Second, your second TD has a width of 94% meaning the other 2 will have a width of 3% each (most likely). That 94% cell contains a button that seems smaller than the first one, giving it all that space seems like an error

Comment: If you can read , and I'm trying to say this nice , you can read that the log out button is not ON THE PHOTO --' but i'll make a new one just for you!

Answer (score -1):

Add `vertical-align:top` to a few things - try the table cells, and if that doesn't fix it try adding it to your submit buttons instead.

Comment: "...to a few things"? What kind of advice is that? Wait for the CSS.